# How do I include a pause for input in DialogFlow?

Tags: node.js, action, dialogflow-es, voice

For example, when I ask the user for a sequence of numbers, I want to be able to take that sequence only after he/she has paused for at least 4 seconds.
e.g.
- "12345..." (pause for one second) "...789" --> taken input: 12345789
- "1234..." (pause for 4 seconds) "...789" --> taken input: 1234

My code:

```
    'confirmNumberIntent' : function(assistant, cache) {
      let userNumber = assistant.getRawInput();
      assistant.setContext('number', 1);

      let confirmNumberMessage = "I heard " + userNumber + ". Is that right?";
      cache.user.lastSpeech = confirmNumberMessage;
      cache.user.promptSpeech = cache.user.lastSpeech;
      assistant = sessionUtil.setData(assistant, cache);
      askWithSuggestion(assistant, cache, ['Yes', 'No']);
    }
```

In Dialogflow:
- the intent name is confirm.number 
- parameter type: @sys.flight-number

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to handle that pause? I'm not sure it is possible, but want to understand what meaning the pause is supposed to have.

Comment: Hi @Prisoner
Our similar situation is similar to the TS above. In our case, we would like to get the PIN from the user which contains 4 digits number.
When I said one two three four with number input, Dialogflow interprets the input with whitespace hence 1 2 3 4 shown in the screen. However, the funny thing is when we debug the console of the value passed by the API, the input only shows the last digit of the user utterance which is 4. It seems that only the last number is treated as the input not the complete sequence of number. Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It sounds like yours is a different issue (getting all the digits), and I'd suggest opening it as a new question, including information about or a screen shot of the Intent you're using to capture it.

Answer (score 0):

The pause you are talking about will be interpreted as blank or break in conversation as the speech to text engine is not that evolved like humans. So you will miss capturing anything spoken after the "pause".

You can set up a slot filling webhook for verification of the input number and if the phone number is not of correct length or as per your requirements, you can reset the context to capture the phone number again and ask the user to say it without a break.

I hope this helps.